# Arrays/Ptr Dynamic Allocation in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a series of values I am "hashing" into 16000000 slots. I must increment the slots to indicate how many hashed into it.

If a slot is needed, it should be initialized to 0 before I begin incrementation.

I'm unfamiliar with malloc() but I understand it may be needed (using C). Ptr/array conventions have always been confusing to me.

I have the following:

```
int (*temp) [16000000]; // ptr to array of 16000000 (unallocated)

for (n)
 (*temp)[hashmap]++; // dereference the pointer, access into array at hashmap to increment

...

for (n)
 if (temp[i] != NULL) // if the array location at the ith position is allocated
   .... = (*temp)[i]; // set some thing equal to the value at that position
```

Are my usages correct so far? If so, how may I dynamically allocate to fulfill my needs?

For reference, I'm a second-year CS student in university.

Comment: No, your usage is not correct. `temp` is an uninitialized pointer. `for (n)` is invalid syntax. `temp[i] != NULL` is not a valid array access given the type of `temp`, but if it were, NULL is also not an appropriate value to compare when dealing with an array of `int` values. You're asking about dynamic allocation but not doing it anywhere. If you want to allocate a zero-initialized block of memory, use `calloc`.

Comment: I'm asking how I would dynamically allocate that array position when I would need it, to be hashed into. temp is uninitialized because I would like to allocate on need only. I thought that, in this case, temp[I] would yield the address of the array at that location, since I have a pointer to an array, and I am only dereferencing once. for (n) was simply laziness to show I am iterating over n values.

Comment: Your pointer to an array must actually point to an array. The language does not magically allocate one for you just because you dereferenced an uninitialized pointer. All it does is invoke undefined behavior. As for _"If a slot is needed, it should be initialized to 0 before I begin incrementation"_ that is overlooking the fact that if it's _not_ initialized then you don't know whether the value it currently holds needs to be initialized or not when you are incrementing it. That's why you should initialize the entire array to zero before starting anything.

Comment: note, depending on where this code appears temp will be allocated in 2 entirely different ways. It is better to show complete code

Answer (score 1):

This would be the easiest way to create an initialized array of integers (or if your counts are positive use `size_t` instead of `int`):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
// ...
int *hash_table = calloc(16000000, sizeof int);
```

Then you do:

```
size_t hash_value = hash_function(key) % (sizeof tmp / sizeof *tmp);
hash_table[hash_value]++;
```

where `key` is the thing you want to assign to a slot (you don't tell us what but could be a string or a number or whatever).

Comment: When you say initialized, wouldn't that allocate them in the heap location and thus use that full 16000000 * sizeof(int) space? My goal is to only allocate the slot IFF it is needed and not before then, to avoid total memory usage since I am dealing with such a huge amount of data that it exceeds all my cache sizes.

Comment: It depends on your operating system, for instance, copy on write (COW) may not actually allocate the array till you write to it.

Comment: Perhaps you need to create a dynamically-growing hash table to store your other hash function collisions. If you want to use an array for this, you will either have no array, or a complete array. FWIW, 16 million is not a "huge" amount of data nowadays, unless perhaps you're running this on some tiny embedded device.

Comment: Would it succeed in only allocating that slot that you write to or would it allocate it by the page?

Comment: I understand. What I'm asking is not possible. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: There is dynamically growing hash tables.  They are somewhat complicated.  An easy way to create a table of size n, then when it's say 50% full, create a new table of size 2n then rehash all keys into the new table (this means you need to keep the keys around so store {key, count} in each entry).

Comment: There are plenty of solutions you _could_ choose. But begin by asking yourself _why_ you can't just allocate the entire array up-front. And if you really want to avoid it, ask yourself how much up-front allocation is acceptable. Let's imagine it's about 16k pointers. Well, you could use one level of indirection by creating an array of 16525 NULL pointers. Each acts as a bucket to collect blocks of 1024 hashes. If a hash needs to go in a bucket that's not initialized, just allocate+initialize 1024 elements and store the pointer. If that's not sparse enough for you, add more indirection.